# ipad: Bigger area for alert on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

```
UIAlertController(title: nil, message: webConsoleLog, preferredStyle: .alert)
```

I have tons of text (web console logs) to present.
How can I tell uialertcontroller to occupy max amount
of screen real estate on tampax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell alerts to grow in size. Maybe a better solution here is to show a modal view controller with the log. Then you can control the size yourself.